# Vim: How to move one word left in command mode

Tags: vim

In Vim command mode, If I'm typing this: (`|` denotes the cursor):

`:e config/application.rb|`

and I want to move to the start of the word `application`:

`:e config/|application.rb`

is there a key sequence that will do this?  According to `:help c_<S-Left>`, I can move one `WORD` left, which would get the cursor here:

`:e |config/application.rb`

but I don't see anything that would move the cursor one `word` left.

Comment: It's the command-line mode, not the command mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to do command editing, particularly for long command, I suggest the command-line window. `:h cmdwin` for details.

In command-line window, you can just edit the command in vim editor. You can use all your vim-fu there.

To enter the cmd-line win, you can either:

- command mode: `<ctrl-f>`
- normal mode: `q:`

Answer (score 3):

There exists a properly released plugin that may help you: [vim-husk](https://github.com/vim-utils/vim-husk). I've provided similar shortcuts in a [hidden plugin (and don't forget the autoload plugin + the dependencies to support utf-8 characters correctly)](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/cmdline-motions.vim) a few weeks ago.

In both case, your move will be bound to `<m-b>`